# Requiring certain columns in SELECT SQL query for it to go through?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am looking for a way to require users of a SQL query system to include certain columns in the SELECT query for example require select to have `transaction_id` column else return error. This is to insure compatibility with other functions.

I'm using `EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON)` to parse query plan as a dictionary but it doesn't provide information about the column names.

Comment: play with views, or rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `EXPLAIN (VERBOSE)`? That shows the column names.

But I think it will be complicated – you'd have to track table aliases to figure out which column belongs to which table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try if it works for me, need to understand its output. What do you recommended as a better way to parse the query or as a better api? Any thoughts about the aliases problem?

Comment: I don't know; it is a difficult and unusual requirement. "Compatibility with other functions" is a bit general - maybe you can share what the real problem is.

Comment: For example a plotting function. Where a column is used as index.

Comment: But if a column is used in the SELECT list of a query, that is no guarantee that it is used in the WHERE clause in a fashion that an index can be used. Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: I meant using the column as index (indices) of a plot in the plot function not as in "table index". In general the idea is to have the column always present in all tables to do plotting, groupings, comparisons, and all sorts of functions. I wasn't vague on purpose it's just a general type of requirement.